# T-SQL return corrected column based on non-exhaustive lookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please forgive what I think should be a fairly simple question, but I'm struggling to find other previous questions with the same conditions.

I have a SQL Server database table which includes a `WorkplaceName` column (`nvarchar`), with many different possibilities for this column, which comes from a different source system, and which cannot be changed upstream.

An example of what this could look like from a select statement of the `MainDataTable`:

```
 WorkplaceName | Value
 ---------------------
 ID1234        | 54
 ID9876        | 99
 ID 2345       | 76
```

Almost all of these entries are correct, however, there are a small number of entries which are incorrect, and for the purpose of downstream data manipulation, I need to correct the few of those locations based on a non-exhaustive lookup table.

Let's assume that 'ID 2345' is badly formed, and should have been ID2345.

I have a lookup table called `WorkplaceLookups` which contains ONLY the entries which are known to be incorrect, along with a  corrected output:

```
 WorkplaceNameReference | WorkplaceNameLookup
 ----------------------------------------------
 'ID 2345'              |  'ID2345'
```

Thus, if a correctly formed Workplace comes through (which is not in the lookup list), I want to return the original value; if a badly formed Workplace exists, it should be corrected with the value in the lookup.

Using SQL-ish pseudocode, this is more or less what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
     WHEN [MainDataTable].[WorkplaceName] IN [WorkplaceLookups].[WorkplaceNameReference]
      THEN [WorkplaceLookups].[WorkplaceNameLookup]
      ELSE [MainDataTable].[WorkplaceName]
   END AS [WorkplaceNameCorrected],
   [Value]
FROM 
   MainDataTable
```

How should I go about it? If at all possible, I would like to avoid any functions or stored procedures, but if the only solution is to use such, then so be it.

Would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Many thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `left outer join` and `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(wl.WorkplaceNameLookup, mdt.WorkplaceName) as WorkplaceNameCorrected,
       Value
FROM MainDataTable mdt LEFT JOIN
     WorkplaceLookups wl
     ON mdt.WorkplaceName = wl.WorkPlaceNameReference;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, that seems to have done it, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IsNull(m.WorkplaceNameLookup, l.WorkplaceName) as WorkplaceName, Value
FROM MainDataTable m LEFT JOIN
 WorkplaceLookups l ON m.WorkplaceName = l.WorkPlaceNameReference
```

hope this will help you.